# HTML & CSS: My image is not appearing?

Tags: html, css

I've just been teaching my self HTML & CSS and I'm running into my first annoying bug.

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/Rk6TjqKZ

It's the only image I have on it so far, and it used to appear, but ever since adding a class to the

I also need help positioning my buttons.

Comment: <a href="" class="classname"> what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: `<a href="#whatever" class="whitespaceSeparated classNames">link text</a>`.

Comment: Bump? Idk if I can bump here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding class is very easy

```
<a href="imgur.com/auZNAV1" class="YOUR_CLASS_NAME">
   <img src="i.imgur.com/auZNAV1.png"; title="Hosted by imgur.com" />
</a>
```

and in your css:

```
.YOUR_CLASS_NAME{
 /* your style definitions like margin-top: 10px. etc etc */
}
```

Comment: @not589 just paste your code here http://pastebin.com/ and click at submit and give me the url

Comment: @not589 ok thanks, i think, it has to do with your class css. try to change ``position: absolute`` or so.

Comment: @not589 i dont know how other things are positioned, it may depend on other elements. so play with all css styles to achieve what you want. if you cannot, post another question regarding this bug.